# Booting from a CD when the keyboard isn't responding

Tags: windows, boot, keyboard

I'm trying to boot into a CD. Unfortunately, I have to "press a key to continue" and my keyboard doesn't load/light up/start responding/etc. until *after* Windows starts. What can I do?

Comment: Is it a USB keyboard?

Comment: err, how do I tell?

Comment: [PS/2 is on the left, USB is on the right](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl75e.jpg)

Comment: Oh. It's a USB.

Comment: do you happen to have a PS/2 keyboard?

Comment: Yes. I plugged that one in, and it lights up, but still doesn't respond to any keystrokes.

Comment: You may need to reboot for the PS/2 keyboard to start working.

Answer (score 0):

You can borrow a PS/2 keyboard or you can get a USB to PS/2 adapter.

Here is one from Amazon for $1.59 with free shipping.
[http://www.amazon.com/USB-to-PS-2-Adapter/dp/B00007AP2O](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00007AP2O)

Comment: That product does exactly the opposite of what you would need in this situation.  If the OP hadn't had a spare PS/2 keyboard, he'd have needed to connect a USB keyboard into a PS/2 port.  The product you've linked to allows you to connect a PS/2 keyboard into a USB port.